# Absolute value of the sum of two complex numbers squared

Tags: complex-numbers

I have two complex numbers in the form
$$U_{1} = Ae^{j \phi}$$ and $$ U_{2} = Be^{j \omega}$$
where $j$ is the imaginary unit.

What is the expansion of $$|U_{1} + U_{2}|^{2}\;?$$

My initial attempt was to use the FOIL method, and that yielded
$$(U_1 + U_2^*)(U_1^* + U_2) = U_{1} U_1^* + U_1 U_2 + U_1^* U_2^* + U_2^* U_{2}$$
$$ = A^2 + B^2 + ABe^{j(\phi + \omega)} + ABe^{-j(\phi + \omega)}.$$

This doesn't line up with the answer I've found online, which gives the result as
$$ |U_{1} + U_{2}|^{2} = U_{1} U_1^* + U_1^* U_2 + U_1 U_2^* + U_2^* U_{2}$$
$$ = A^2 + B^2 + ABe^{j(\phi - \omega)} + ABe^{j(\omega - \phi)}.$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why didn't you take $(U_1+U_2)(U_1^*+U_2^*)$?

Comment: There shouldn’t be an imaginary unit in the answer because absolute value (and the square of absolute value) are real.

Answer (score 3):

$|z|^2=zz^\ast$.

Take $z=U_1+U_2$ to get $|U_1+U_2|^2=(U_1+U_2)(U_1+U_2)^\ast=(U_1+U_2)(U_1^\ast+U_2^\ast)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yup thanks a bunch!